# php script doesn't work under different version of MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE pelatis (pelatisKodikos SERIAL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    pelatisEponymo VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , pelatisOnoma VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
    pelatisAT VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL , pelatisDieythinsi VARCHAR(40) NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (pelatisKodikos)) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The CreateTablePelatis.php works fine in my PC (**Server version: %s 5.5.5-10.1.19-MariaDB** ) but not in other  PC (**Server version: %s 5.5.5-10.4.16-MariaDB**) where the following error message appears

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'AUTO_INCREMENT , pelatisEponymo VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
> pelatisOnoma VARC...' at line 1

Comment: It seems redundant to define `SERIAL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`. According to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/es/data-types/SERIAL/), `SERIAL` is already defining both `NOT NULL` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`. So I assume that's what it's complaining about. I can't pinpoint why the older server version allows it, but maybe a change was made to no longer silently ignore duplicate definitions.

Comment: Using the site https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/
it seems that the sql statement is not the problem.

Comment: Nevermind the syntax checker, try it in your application. Put only `SERIAL` there and see if the problem persists.

Comment: The behavior changed between MariaDB 10.1 and 10.2, from 10.2 on forward combining SERIAL type with (redundant) AUTO_INCREMENT is no longer supported. I have not found out why this was changed yet though ...

Comment: You were both (El_Vanja and Hartmut HoLtzgraefe) absolutely RIGHT and THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH indeed!!
My script worked fine when I removed the "NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT" part.
Again: THANK YOU VERY MUCH you were  very very helpful.